# How to declare style in propTypes?

Tags: react-native, eslint

With the [forbid-prop-types](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/forbid-prop-types.md) rule enabled, `eslint` forbids me from using `style: React.PropTypes.object`, and using `shape` is suggested.

But is it really necessary to define all the available properties there for this purpose like this?

```
DEMO.propTypes = {
    style: React.PropTypes.shape({
        color: React.PropTypes.string,
        fontSize: React.PropTypes.number,
        ...
    })
};
```

Too much definition code!

Comment: Future readers, let me save you some time, see the answer by [@David Weldon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39627920/812919)

Answer (score 76):

React Native now contains `ViewPropTypes`, which will replace `View.propTypes.style`. Example of usage:

```
import { ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native';

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  style: ViewPropTypes.style
};
```

Comment: Have you seen an equivalent for Text? TextPropTypes doesn't seem to exist  in the React Native codebase   View.propTypes no longer exists at run-time in release mode, am not sure yet whether Text.propTypes does hthough.

Comment: @BenClayton I have not. The RN documentation for ViewPropTypes isn’t available atm either.

Comment: Its deprecated for react-native-web
https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/releases/tag/0.12.0

Answer (score 38):

```
View.propTypes.style
```

or

```
Text.propTypes.style
```

It would look like this:

```
DEMO.propTypes = {
    style: Text.propTypes.style,
    ...
};
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.21/docs/style.html#pass-styles-around

Comment: The question is tagged `reactjs`, is this `react-native` only?

Comment: This is `react-native` only, but it's definitely the best answer for `react-native` :)

Comment: this is now deprecated

Comment: Carefull! `View.propTypes` will be stripped out in release builds so you will have an error: `style of undefined`!! (Same for `Text`)

Comment: This solution is outdated. Try with the answer of @NiFi. That worked for me

Comment: This solution is deprecated since React Native 0.44. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1352

Answer (score 21):

One possibility is to use the [react-style-proptype](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-style-proptype) package like so:

```js
import stylePropType from 'react-style-proptype';

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  style: stylePropType,
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately this package throws warnings with some RN style settings like `paddingHorizontal`.

Answer (score 16):

Use the simple code as below.

```js
PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object, PropTypes.array])
```

So, you can apply to this your code.

```js
DEMO.propTypes = {
    style: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object, PropTypes.array]),
};
```

Tested in RN > 0.57.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ViewPropTypes.style`. `View.propTypes` has been deprecated

Comment: ViewPropTypes is no longer in the docs. Deprecated I presume.

Comment: So is there an alternative? Edit: looks like `ViewStyle` is now supported

Answer (score 4):

**Quick and dirty / Hack-ish**

Extending @jalal246 answer:

```
PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.string,
    PropTypes.number,
]))
```

This can be used for web styles (refer other answers for React-native) without having to use other package for it.

Comment: This allows non-style keys in the object.

Comment: Yeah, this is quick and dirty.

Answer (score 3):

As some of the former answers are depricated, so I will share my solution here.

In fact, you could simply import the original types, such as `ViewStyle`, `TextStyle`, `ImageStyle`, `FlexStyle` & `ImageStyle` from react-native.

For example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';

interface IProps {
    style?: ViewStyle
}

<TouchableOpacity style={[props.style]}>
    ...
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Remarks:
If you are using 3-rd party libraries that supports TypeScript, there should be relevant style property as well, just like in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string)` no need to define all css style.

Comment: This allows non-style keys in the object.

Comment: This also doesn't let you use, for example, left: 0 as a number which would instead need to be left: '0px'

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities. The first one, which I prefer, is to use ViewPropTypes from react. The other one, using PropTypes, is:

```
Component.propTypes = {
    textStyles: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.object,
        PropTypes.number
    ])
}
```

You may ask "why PropTypes.number if a style is just an object?" the answer is that the react native team made a little optimization which caches the stylesheet and simply sends the cached ID.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy way with JSDoc.

```
/**
   * @typedef Props
   * @prop {React.CSSProperties} style
   */

/**
 * some component
 * @augments {Component<Props, State>}
 */

 export default class SomeRandomClass extends React.Component { }
```

Adding above JSDoc to your react component will enable VS Code to suggest all possible CSS properties.