# What is the prop type for StyleSheet validation

Tags: react-native, react-proptypes

I'm writing components for our react-native project

I get this error from prop-types

"Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `containerStyle` of type `number` supplied to `ImagePicker`, expected `object`."

Simplified example:

common-styles.js

```
    export const defaultStyle = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        color: 'red',
        borderWidth: 2
      }
    });
```

image-picker.js

```
    ImagePicker.propTypes = {
      containerStyle: PropTypes.shape(),
    };
```

app.js

```
    <ImagePicker containerStyle={styles.defaultStyle} />
```

What is the PropType for passing Stylesheet variables?

Thank you

Comment: Where is `styles` (of `containerStyle={styles.defaultStyle}`) being defined?

Comment: Here are some of the possible solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34626298/how-to-declare-style-in-proptypes

Comment: @acdcjunior hello, as mentioned it is from common-syles.js

Comment: @Susth, thanks tried it, although I am getting an error if i use array `<ImagePicker containerStyle={[form_input.pads, { borderWidth: 1 }]}  />`, I'll be checking this again and see if I can workaround the array issue

Answer (score 4):

```
import { ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native';
ImagePicker.propTypes = {
  containerStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
};
```

Ref: [facebook/react-native /Libraries/Components/View/ViewPropTypes.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/f1316cab6c351852ef1da9939d4c8f0244fb8a6f/Libraries/Components/View/ViewPropTypes.js#L377)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the type `number` was valid since it's the actual styles are saved in an aggregated styles object. Only the lookup IDs are passed

see [StyleSheet documentation here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html#flatten)

The correct PropTypes should be

```
    ImagePicker.propTypes = {
      containerStyle: PropTypes.number,
    };
```