# iOS : App crash in release mode. Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.View.propTypes.style')

Tags: ios, react-native, react-proptypes, xcode9.3

Yes! There are many questions and answers related to this but in every solution, all people say to replace `View.propTypes.style` with `ViewPropTypes.style`. But in my project, there is not `View.propTypes.style` code available in the whole project.

If in my project `View.propTypes.style` is not available then where can i replace?

Full error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.View.propTypes.style')
 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.View.propTypes.style')
[290:10014] Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.View.propTypes.style')
[290:10014] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.View.propTypes.style')', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.View.prop..., stack:
<unknown>@1022:1541
t@2:620
```

---

For reference i have using `propTypes` at below point but i think it's not an issue.

```
const propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.array,
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    initValue: PropTypes.string,
    style: ViewPropTypes.style,
    selectStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
    optionStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
    optionTextStyle: Text.propTypes.style,
    sectionStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
    sectionTextStyle: Text.propTypes.style,
    cancelStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
    cancelTextStyle: Text.propTypes.style,
    overlayStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
    cancelText: PropTypes.string
};
```

Comment: Also check your node_modules folder. Some libraries may be using it.

Comment: @Nakamura I have checked everywhere in my directory. also, I searched this in whole project and directory with command but there is no specific word is available in the directory.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34626298/how-to-declare-style-in-proptypes/39627920#39627920