# How to resolve -Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'i.View.propTypes.style') in React native

Tags: android, react-native, android-bundle

It has been couple of days since I am facing this issue, after researching for a while I thought I would ask here in case any one could help.

I have a react native app running currently on `Android` and it comes up with the following error.

`Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'i.View.propTypes.style')`

After going through the same questions asked previously, 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16542

Here are my findings.

I have looked for `'View.propTypes.style'` in the entire code base and replaced with `ViewPropTypes.style`

I also did a search in the `node_modules` and none of the libraries I have are using it.

And what I found is `View.PropTypes.style` is in the following files

- index.android.bundle (android\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug)
- index.android.bundle (android\app\src\main\assets)

I have also noticed that it does not happen always. some times it just works (irrespective of debug mode)

Here is the screenshot of my search

[image]

I tried editing these files and rerun the project but it goes back to the original state.

How can I edit these files.

Am I missing to do anything here.

Could you please suggest on how to resolve this.

Thanks
R

Comment: Have you tried to initialize a new project with the last react-native version and add your personal app code on this newly created one?

Comment: React native version my project is currently on -  "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.4",

I have not tried that though. how does that help?

Comment: Its most likely cached in the build files if you really removed it and it goes back to original state on run time.

Comment: If cleaning the cache don't works for you, remember that after a change comes the bug fixing so, from your version to the latest you could find several if not yours problems solved.

Comment: @Perniferous do you mean the content in `index.android.bundle`. am I allowed to edit it?. if so once edited how can I stop it from going back to original state?

Comment: okay I think I know how to clean the cache. so basically what you are suggesting is to edit the `index.android.bundle` clean the cache and re run is that right?

Comment: You're deleting generated files from the build directory. What you have replaced, will just replace itself after a new build. Delete the `build` directory within the `project_root/android directory` and rebuild your project. Make sure you close down your Metro Bundler as well. This is to ensure you have a clean build.  Could you post a screenshot of the error?

Comment: for me Admob integration did that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34626298/how-to-declare-style-in-proptypes/39627920#39627920